# Adding multiple Photos to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcmap, geotag, arcgis-online

I'm trying to add almost 400 geotagged photos to ArcGIS Online (AGOL) for a work project but with no avail.

I've tried converting the geotagged photos to points in ArcMap and bringing this in to AGOL, which only displays the URL and doesn't have the photo.

Currently uploading them to Flickr to add as a KML link, but I don't want them to be public.

The AGOL story map is only suitable for up to 50 photos and uploading 400 at a time to AGOL is futile.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: You have probably read this: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/09/12/photos-images-arcgis-online/ , in the comments they discuss batch uploading which does not seem to be supported

Comment: Import points to fgdb, enable attachments and add them all at once. Share as sevice